# SectionedFetchRequest - Sort by field in relationship object

Tags: core-data

I have a Entity called Project, this has a relationship called statusOrder to another entity called Status.

In status, it has a field called sortOrder which is Int16. What I'm wanting to do is to sort by this sortOrder as part of a sectioned fetch request.

I've tried doing as below, but for some reason its only returning 1 section, which is has an id of nil, rather than 5 sections all with Int16 ids.

```
@SectionedFetchRequest(
sectionIdentifier: \Project.statusOrder?.sortOrder,
sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Project.statusOrder?.sortOrder, ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Project.name, ascending: true)],
predicate: NSPredicate(format: "status != %@", "Wish List"),
animation: .default)
```

[image: This is what I'm getting]

[image: This is how I want]